# Issues in for loop for finding Prime number in C, Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio, for-loop, primes

I wrote a simple for loop in C to find if entered number is a prime number. Upon running, even when entering simple values like 7, 13, etc. the programme just sits on it and seems to be processing something huge. I have an i53340M so processing power really isnt an issue. CPU usage shoots up to 25% on all cores and I see no result even after few minutes of waiting. Of course, modern processors are not slow and C is very fast, much faster than Python, which itself is cabale of checking for prime very swiftly.

It seems to me that I have done something stupid and left the code unoptimised or bloated. Please take a look and tell me where I went wrong :

```
    int num,i,chk = 0 ;
    printf("\nEnter positive integer to check : ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    for (i = 2; i = num / 2; i++)
    {
        if (num%i == 0)
        {
            break;
            chk = 1;
        }
    }
    if(num == 1)
        printf("\n\n1 is neither prime not composite.\n");
    else if(chk == 1)
        printf("\n\nThe number %d is indeed prime.\n", num);
    else
        ("\n\nThe number %d is not actually prime.\n", num);
```

Comment: Have you considered tracing through in a debugger to see what's happening? `num` never changes, so think about how your loop works if the break is never hit. Maybe you meant to use `<` in the comparison instead?

Comment: @RetiredNinja Sorry, I didnt quite get you... why does num changing matter... i is supposed to change to test num%i , right ?

Comment: Does `i = num / 2` as your loop condition look right to you?

Comment: In the future, always provide a [mre] when asking about code that is not working. Do not provide just a code fragment.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Sure, I will, I understand.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Aha ! I get it now !

Comment: Statements after a `break` don't get executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i = num / 2` assigns `num / 2` to `i` and evaluates as “true” to continue the `for` loop.  (when `n` is greater than 1). You may have intended `i <= num / 2`.

Comment: I'm having a new issue now, the programme is not actually printing wether the number is prime or not. It checks the number, and then proceeds to terminate. Why isnt it printing the appropriate result ? is there somthing wrong with my if statements ?

Comment: It does print 1 is neither prime not composite when I enter 1...

Comment: What about this piece of code: ```if (num%i == 0){ break; chk = 1; }``` ?

Comment: @Lucas What about it ?

Comment: Should order of statements inside if block not be ```{chk = 1; break;}```?

Comment: @Lucas Months later, i come back here , and this code is a blithering, unreadable, ridiculous mess, thanks for having the patience to help me with it